# Change password ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Im working in a app in ASP.NET MVC3 and Im trying that the user can change his password but i don't know why my code doesn't work. 
Here I attach you the code.

MODEL CLASS:

```
public class CambioContraseña
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Contraseña actual")]
    public string ContraseñaVieja { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "La contraseña debe tener un minimo de 6 caracteres.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Contraseña nueva")]
    public string ContraseñaNueva { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirma nueva contraseña")]
    [Compare("ContraseñaNueva", ErrorMessage = "La nueva contraseña y la contraseña de confirmación no coinciden.")]
    public string ConfirmarContraseñaNueva { get; set; }
}
```

CONTROLLER CLASS:

```
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult CambiarContraseña()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/ChangePassword

    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CambiarContraseña(CambioContraseña model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            LogOn logon = new LogOn();
            Registro registro = new Registro();
            // ChangePassword will throw an exception rather
            // than return false in certain failure scenarios.
            bool cambioContraseñaCorrecto;
            try
            {
                //MembershipUser usuarioActual = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name, true /* userIsOnline */);
                //cambioContraseñaCorrecto = usuarioActual.ChangePassword(model.ContraseñaVieja, model.ContraseñaNueva);
                cambioContraseñaCorrecto = logon.ExisteUsuario(registro.idUsuario);
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs"].ConnectionString);
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("update Usuario set contraseña='" + model.ContraseñaNueva + "' where idUsuario='" + registro.idUsuario + "'", connection);
                object comandoRetorno = command.ExecuteScalar();
                connection.Close();


            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                cambioContraseñaCorrecto = false;
            }
            if (cambioContraseñaCorrecto)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("CambioContraseñaCorrecto");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "La actual contraseña es inválida o la nueva contraseña es incorrecta.");
            }
        }
        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

VIEW CLASS:

```
@model FutbookPFC.Models.CambioContraseña

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Futbook / Configuración";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutGenerico.cshtml";
}

<h2>CambiarContraseña</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"   type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Cambio de contraseña incorrecto. Por favor, corrige los errores e intentelo de nuevo.")
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Contraseña</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ContraseñaVieja)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ContraseñaVieja)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ContraseñaVieja)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ContraseñaNueva)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ContraseñaNueva)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ContraseñaNueva)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmarContraseñaNueva)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmarContraseñaNueva)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmarContraseñaNueva)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Cambiar Contraseña" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

}

Any idea to solve it?
Thanks!!

Comment: Something to do with not using parameters for your sql command?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be you use a name with a international character inside the update where statement.
As a consequence, if the username is saved as varchar (you don't have a N') it won't find anything, which means it doesn't update anything.

Hint: 
 
`Update T_Whatever WHERE Username =`'abcñxyz'`.`
instead of 
`Update T_Whatever WHERE Username =`N'abcñxyz'`.`

PS: 
I can use SQL-injection to create my own user.
Try username or password: d'Alambert.

Additionally, you should use IDbConnection and IDbCommand instead of SqlConnection and SqlCommand, because else, you won't just have to change the SQL once you change the database.

And try to use A class for your database access functions.

Additionally, use stored procedures instead of hard-coding your SQL strings.
That way you can fix SQL-errors (e.g. improve its performance) without having to recompile your application once it is deployed to production.

And additonally, you use registro.idUsuario, without ever initializing the class to something else than the default value.